# OS regional settings and browser language

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I'm working on an asp.net project where we need to localize the UI according to 2 different sources.

The most common scenario is when the user is logged in. In our user management system we know which language is his preferred language. In this case, all is fine and easy.

The other scenario is when the user is not logged in yet. In this case we use the browser language.
To find it out, we use the following piece of code

```
if (Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0)
{
    //USE THE LANGUAGE
}
```

We have a user that reports us that he did not changed his browser language but his OS regional settings and yet it influenced the language used in the application...

That sounds very weird to me...
Sadly the user is not an IT guy and struggles at giving any more useful information.

Does any one of you ever heard that this is possible? To me it seems like that should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting two properties for your application in `<system.web>` section of application's `web.config` file?

```
 <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

Both `culture` and `uiCulture` properties need to be set to behave accordingly based on user language selection.

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work. It still returns "en-us" instead of "en-gb".